Past and future tenses
"I saw she's gorgeous"
Is this sentence correct. I  was taught to never use present or future tenses after past ones in on sentecne. If it's wrong. How can I correct it?

The sentence is a bit odd, but not bad syntax. Consider I heard she’s allergic to wheat. It’s admittedly the case that in such sentences was would sound more natural.

This is similar to the much-discussed issue of 'reported speech about things that are still true' - He said that the sun rises in the east and so on.  There is no fixed rule about which tense to use. Assuming that the woman is still 'gorgeous', is isn't wrong to use the present tense, but most native speakers would say "I saw [that] she was gorgeous" (that's how she looked at the moment I first saw her).

@KateBunting. Here we have "I saw" that's why I thought it's different not 'said or heard". "That" is optional, right?

Yes, that is optional, that's why I put it in square brackets!

Backshifting is optional if the situation is still true.
We backshift if the situation has changed, or if we are not sure of it:

I saw (that) she was gorgeous


I said (that) she was gorgeous


I heard (that) she was gorgeous

The same logic applies when we use said or heard.
